# Using Wand gives 'MagickCompareImagesLayers' not found Error

Tags: python-3.x, imagemagick, wand

I am trying to use ImageMagick in Python3.7 using Wand binding. I have successfully installed ImageMagick & Wand(pip install, version: 0.5.7) But I'm constantly getting the error that says: 
***'AttributeError: function 'MagickCompareImagesLayers' not found'***

I followed the below steps as mentioned in official Wand Document
[(link here)](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.2-maintenance/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-windows)!:
1) Installed ImageMagick Binary from official website (windows, 64bit version)
2) Once installed, added the path to System Variables with name 'MAGICK_HOME' 
3) Installed Wand using pip

Config: 
     -- platform.attribute() - ('64bit', 'WindowsPE');
     -- Python3.7.4; 
     -- Wand==0.5.7; 
     -- ImageMagick-6.9.10-35-Q8-x64-dll

Running the following command after the above steps:

```py
from wand.image import Image
```

yields following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in from wand.image import Image

File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 18, in from . import assertions

File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\assertions.py", line 125, in from .color import Color # noqa: E402

File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\color.py", line 10, in from .api import library

File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\api.py", line 205, in traceback.format_exc())

ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found or incompatible Original exception was raised in: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\api.py", line 196, in magick_image.load(library, IM_VERSION.value) File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\cdefs\magick_image.py", line 228, in load lib.MagickCompareImagesLayers.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_int] File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 377, in getattr func = self.getitem(name) File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 382, in getitem func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self)) AttributeError: function 'MagickCompareImagesLayers' not found

Getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-4c9b1a6583e4>", line 1, in <module>
    from wand.image import Image

  File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import assertions

  File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\assertions.py", line 125, in <module>
    from .color import Color  # noqa: E402

  File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\color.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .api import library

  File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\api.py", line 205, in <module>
    traceback.format_exc())

ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found or incompatible
Original exception was raised in:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\api.py", line 196, in <module>
    magick_image.load(library, IM_VERSION.value)
  File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wand\cdefs\magick_image.py", line 228, in load
    lib.MagickCompareImagesLayers.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_int]
  File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 377, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "c:\users\surya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 382, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'MagickCompareImagesLayers' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by trial and error. Following steps worked for me:

1) Uninstall ImageMagick
2) Uninstall Wand
3) Install 6.6-x Binary of ImageMagick: ImageMagick-6.6.9-10-Q16-windows-x64-dll
[(Here's a link with old binaires)](http://web.archive.org/web/20110921004715/http://mhonarc.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/)
4) Install Wand(0.5.7)

Voila, it works now.